# Cwac-camera crash when picture taken

Tags: android, camera, commonsware-cwac

When my picture is taken via **takePicture()** function, Cwac-camera crash (depending device, work well on Desire HD, crash on Nexus S).

Referring to this post : [camera.setParameters failed in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890381/camera-setparameters-failed-in-android)

I would like to know how to do this with Cwac-camera.

**Backtrace:**

```
07-03 20:58:57.207  24659-24659/com.xxxxxx                    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
    at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1410)
    at com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraView$OnOrientationChange.onOrientationChanged(CameraView.java:413)
    at android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl.onSensorChanged(OrientationEventListener.java:143)
    at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$ListenerDelegate$1.handleMessage(SystemSensorManager.java:204)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your trace has a `caused by` part.

Answer (score 0):

This crash is not coming from `takePicture()`. If you look at the stack trace, you will not see `takePicture()`. Instead, this is coming from an orientation change. Specifically, you appear to have the device locked to an orientation, causing `CameraView` to use sensors to detect the device orientation to try to adjust the camera settings, and we're dying there.

If you can reproduce this problem with the demo app, please [file an issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues) with the steps to reproduce it, as I cannot reproduce it on a Nexus S with the demo app.

If you cannot reproduce this problem with the demo app, and you can publish a reproducible test case, please [file an issue with the source code to the reproducible test case](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues).

Otherwise, you will have to hope that the problem that you are experiencing is related to [this issue on switching cameras with the Nexus S](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/8), and then further hope that I can figure out what that problem is.

Comment: I'm working with v.0.0.2 and set android:screenOrientation="portrait" locked to my AndroidManifest.xml. Have you tried with this. Regards,

Comment: @QuentinRousseau: I'll take a look at it sometime this weekend, if all goes well.

Comment: Precision: Work well when android:screenOrientation="portrait" is not setted but crash when orientation changed. Regards,

Comment: @QuentinRousseau: OK, I can reproduce the problem and I have it at least minimized, possibly outright fixed. Monitor https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/12 to learn when I publish the update containing the fix.

Comment: @CommonsWare- how to hide the action bar??the preview is stopped if i use actionbar.hide(); in the MainActivity.