# Cwac-camera and Nexus S Portrait - Strange Bitmap size

Tags: android, camera, nexus-s, commonsware-cwac

Probleme with the Nexus S , after a first probleme [Cwac-camera crash when picture taken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456247/cwac-camera-crash-when-picture-taken/17578440#17578440):

**I take a photo with a screenOrientation:portrait, but a catch a Landscape picture, so with a rotation of 90°**

**In the code**

In my SimpleCameraHost extended class, the bitmap received have the dimension of a landscape image

```
@Override
public void saveImage(byte[] image)
{
      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
...
```

LOG bitmap.getWidth => 2560

LOG bitmap.getHeight => 1920

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orientation of the photo should match the *actual* orientation of the device. IOW, if the device is held in portrait, the image should be portrait. If the device is held in landscape, the image should be landscape. The choice of `android:screenOrientation` value (or not having it at all) should not affect those results -- it will merely affect the way that your UI behaves.

I just tested this on a Nexus S, and the rear-facing camera is working as expected. I added `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to the demo app, and when the device is held in portrait mode, the photos are saved in portrait, and when the device is held in landscape mode, the photos are saved in landscape.

If you believe that you have evidence to the contrary, create a sample project that reproduces the error, and [file an issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues) on the project, posting that sample project and the steps in running it to reproduce the error.

---

**UPDATE**

OK, I think I understand now what you're seeing. `Bitmap.decodeByteArray()` apparently pays attention to EXIF headers, whereas a lot of image viewers do not. The Nexus S behaves differently from the other Samsung devices that I have tested so far, and I need to do a little cleanup work on those headers for Nexus S output. I have added [an issue about this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues), and I will hopefully be able to work on this soon.

BTW, I also have logged [an enhancement request](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues) to give you a `Bitmap` via another `saveImage()` method, to avoid your having to decode the `byte[]`.

Comment: In the Demo project
-i override the **saveImage()** function. i have the same Logs. An image of 2560*1920.
-in Landscape an image of 640*480.
-When a i want use the Font-facing camera, the app Crash

Comment: @DamienRomito: "When a i want use the Font-facing camera, the app Crash" -- as noted in the question you linked to, this is already filed as a bug: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/8