# Android setting focus area on camera parameters caused java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed

Tags: android, android-camera, autofocus

I have use `cameraParameters.getMaxNumFocusAreas()` to check and got 10. But when I tap a area on view, I create a list to contain that new focus area.

```
if (cameraParameters.getMaxNumFocusAreas() >= areaList.size()) {
  cameraParameters.setFocusAreas(areaList);
  camera.setParameters(cameraParameters);
}
```

My android Phone has these focusModes: `[continuous-video, auto, macro, infinity, infinity, continuous-picture]`

But will cause java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed. Did I miss something?

Or is there any way to do manual focus for the camera, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [camera.setParameters failed in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890381/camera-setparameters-failed-in-android)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130482/android-camera-setting-focus-area-causing-runtime-exception