# Android camera - setting focus area causing runtime exception

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to develop code that automatically focuses on a large object in the middle of the camera frame.  Here's my code:

```
        Log.i (TAG, "Picking supported size " + selected.width + "x" + selected.height);
        parameters.setPictureSize (selected.width, selected.height);
        try
        {
            parameters.setFocusAreas (Arrays.asList (
                new Camera.Area (
                    new Rect(selected.width/3, selected.height/3, (selected.width*2)/3, (selected.height*2)/3), 
                    1)
                ));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.w (TAG, "Set focus area failed", e);
        }
        catch (NoClassDefFoundError e)
        {
            Log.w (TAG, "Set focus area failed", e);                
        }
        camera.setParameters (parameters);
```

The results on a Samsung Galaxy S2 with CM9 are:

```
I/ImageCaptureActivity(28885): Picking supported size 2048x1232
E/ISecCameraHardware(1874): android::status_t android::ISecCameraHardware::checkArea(ssize_t, ssize_t, ssize_t, ssize_t, ssize_t): Camera area right coordinate is invalid 1365
E/ISecCameraHardware(1874): android::status_t android::ISecCameraHardware::setFocusAreas(const android::CameraParameters&): FocusArea parsing failed
W/dalvikvm(28885): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a641f8)
E/AndroidRuntime(28885): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(28885): java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
E/AndroidRuntime(28885):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(28885):    at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1423)
E/AndroidRuntime(28885):    at net.meridiandigital.autophoto.ImageCaptureActivity$1.run(ImageCaptureActivity.java:67)
```

Any idea why this code isn't working?  The right hand coordinate being produced (1365) is well within the image width (2048), so why is the system objecting to it?

Comment: So, what was your final code?

Comment: I just changed the Rect constructor parameters to -333,-333,333,333 and it worked for me then @PandiriDeepak

Comment: can you even share the weight you used? no change for me after changing my code to -333,-333,333,333.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the documentation of [getFocusAreas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getFocusAreas%28%29), which doubles as the documentation for setFocusAreas,

> Each focus area is a rectangle with specified weight. The direction is
>   relative to the sensor orientation, that is, what the sensor sees. The
>   direction is not affected by the rotation or mirroring of
>   setDisplayOrientation(int). Coordinates of the rectangle range from
>   -1000 to 1000. (-1000, -1000) is the upper left point. (1000, 1000) is the lower right point

So I'd say the 1365 is definitely out of bounds.

Comment: Doh.  I just *assumed* pixels were the coordinate space. :(

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make, and it's not like the internet is littered with examples of working with the camera focus area. Hope it works well for you!

Comment: So is there a method that maps pixels from screen location to **what the camera sees** between -1000 and 1000?