# Camera app with Auto Focus and Flash Light

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

I am developing a camera app in android (without using intent) where , i am implementing both auto focus and Flash light features . It works fine if i implement any one feature. But on adding both Auto focus and Flash Light feature, it gives force close in LG nexus and other phones which has Flash Light. i am using the below code for auto focus and Flash Light.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
    {
        event.startTracking();
        camera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);
        Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
        p.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);

        if(this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH))
        {

            p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
            camera.setParameters(p);
            camera.startPreview();
            camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpgCallback);
        }

        else
        {
            camera.startPreview();
            camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpgCallback);
        }
        return true;

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

     private AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback() 
    {

     @Override
     public void onAutoFocus(boolean autoFocusSuccess, Camera camera)
      {
            camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpgCallback);
              if (autoFocusHandler != null)
              {
                 Message message = autoFocusHandler.obtainMessage(autoFocusMessage, success);
                 autoFocusHandler.sendMessageDelayed(message, AUTOFOCUS_INTERVAL_MS);
                  autoFocusHandler = null;
               }
               else
               {

               }
    }
};
```

This is the Error Log i am getting.

http://txtup.co/WCYjl

What may be the problem. Please Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just had a quick read through the Camera docs, and it looks like you've missed the Surface Holder.

> Important: Pass a fully initialized SurfaceHolder to
>   setPreviewDisplay(SurfaceHolder). Without a surface, the camera will
>   be unable to start the preview.

Have a read through the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Here is an answer which shows how to use this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3964460/2045570

Comment: can you please post the rest of your code? Also where is this happening? What is on line 914?

Comment: Its giving force close on this line.               camera.setParameters(p);

Comment: Whatever you're doing, you are choosing the wrong parameters for the device. I can help you if you post the rest of your code where you set values for p (eg: anything similar to p.setFocusMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);)

Comment: Or before you set caemra Parameters , you can use camera.getParameters().flatten() to log all the parameters that the camera supports. So you can use the right parameter.

Comment: @sanjana check out my revised answer.