# Android :To stored captured image in android that must be same size in every devices

Tags: android

Is it possible to store captured image from camera into Sdcard that shold be 50kb only and it should be same sized when i am capturing image from different different devices.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code

```
Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.set("jpeg-quality", 70);
parameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
parameters.setPictureSize(2048, 1232);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Set this parameters , not sure but may be this can help you ...

Comment: it returns me this type of error java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed.

Comment: Have a look at this thread   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890381/camera-setparameters-failed-in-android