# Android camera setPreviewSize and setPictureFormat exception on Samsung Galaxy Tab Active

Tags: android, camera

I have a problem on one device at field : Samsung Galaxy Tab Active

```
 parameters.setPreviewSize(1280, 720);
 parameters.setPictureSize(1280, 720);
 parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
```

leads to:

Full Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1651)
com.dis.terminal2.activity.CameraActivity.onCreate(CameraActivity.java:149)
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
```

It is not supporting this picture size and/or format.
Unfortunatelly I do not have access to this device,. I am also not able to find it in any specifications. Can somebody check what are the supported sizes and format ? If he has the device :)

Comment: Talented programmers write their apps to check the supported sizes on the fly, [using `getSupportedPictureSizes()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPictureSizes%28%29) and [`getSupportedPreviewSizes()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes()), then choose the sizes based on algorithms and/or user input. `JPEG` support is a requirement AFAIK, so that's not your problem.

Comment: try to see [this][1]
it work for me

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890381/camera-setparameters-failed-in-android